# Intellisense for Angularjs not working on Visual Studio code

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I've been trying so hard to get intellisense work for angular in VS Code and found a many solutions which are deprecated. I'm using the latest version (1.9) of VS code. I've already installed typings and typings for angular in my work folder and also have the "Typings" folder in it but still couldn't get the intellisense to work. Any solutions??

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting vscode? If so, try setting up a `tsconfig.json` file, and add an include to the `index.d.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jsconfig.json file with

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

in your angular root directory and intellisense will work.
More information on: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: @Nizdo Tried it, ain't working..

Answer (score 0):

I followed http://www.bardev.com/2016/06/21/using-visual-studio-code-ceate-angularjs-applications/ article on the version (1.9) but I couldn't get it to work and I just updated to version (1.13.1) and followed the same process again and it's working. Didn't know why it didn't worked or it worked in the intermediate releases (1.10 - 1.13) but it's working in the latest release.
[image: Angular Intellisense is working well]